# SQS log ingestion to Redshift / S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-sqs

We have a requirement to publish log data to Redshift, The logs are currently sent to our SQS queue by another service. We are able to process the messages/logs and extract the required data points/columns using a python script in the lambda function.

What is the best way to move this data to Redshift / S3 for business users to query this data in a partitioned way.

The SQS queue is a standard queue and there is a time component within the message that can be used to partition this data downstream but I am not sure how to use the data within a message to write it out to S3 when there are multiple invocations of the same lambda function, the data volumn is too high to process via single lambda.

Please suggest any design options to partition the data on the fly while getting processed via lambda. I can remove duplicates downstream in the Redshift/S3 environment so duplicate messages can be processed and stored

Comment: This should generally be dealt with via Kinesis streams and Kinesis Firehose.